# Show that $(X_{t})_{t\in[0,1]}$ of i.i.d random variables with non-degenerate distribution has no continuous modification

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am working on an exercise stating as follows:

> Let $(X_{t})_{t\in [0,1]}$ be an (uncountable) family of i.i.d random variables with non-degenerate distribution. Prove that no modification of this process can be continuous.

I have some attempt but cannot proceed:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be the probability space over which $(X_{t})$ is defined. Suppose $X_{t}$ has a continuous modification $\tilde{X}_{t}$. That is, there exists a $\Omega_{0}\subset\Omega$ with $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{0})=1$ such that we can define a random function $\tilde{X}:\Omega_{0}\times T\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\tilde{X}_{t}(\omega)$ is continuous in $t$ for all $\omega\in\Omega_{0}$ and $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ only differ on a set $\Omega\setminus\Omega_{0}$ with probability $0$.

Then, note that, in the aspect of $X_{t}$, not all events are elements of $\mathcal{F}$. For instance $$A:=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega,t)=0\ \text{for all}\ t\in [0,1]\}=\bigcap_{t\in[0,1]}\{X(\omega, t)=0\},$$ since this is an uncountable intersection of measurable events from $\mathcal{F}$.

However, since $\tilde{X}_{t}$ is continuous on, then we can depict $$B:=\{\omega\in\Omega_{0}:\tilde{X}(\omega,t)=0\ \text{for all}\ t\in[0,1]\}=\bigcap_{t\in D}\{\omega\in\Omega_{0}:\tilde{X}(\omega,t)=0\},$$ where $D$ is a dense countable subset of $[0,1]$, for instance, $D=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Therefore, $B\in\mathcal{F}$.

**Then I got stuck, and for now I haven't even used the i.i.d and non-degenerate.... what should I do to get contradiction? Thank you!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: let $t_n \in [0,1]$ be any sequence of distinct numbers converging to some $t$.  Then the sequence of random variables $Y_n := \tilde{X}_{t_n}$ are iid with a non-degenerate distribution.  If $\tilde{X}$ were really continuous, then this sequence would converge a.s. to $\tilde{X}_t$.  However, show that a sequence of iid non-degenerate random variables converges with probability 0.

There are a number of ways to do the latter.  One approach: use the non-degeneracy of the distribution to show that there exist two disjoint open sets $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(Y_n \in U) > 0$ and $P(Y_n \in V) > 0$.  Use the Borel zero-one law to show that, with probability 1, we have $Y_n \in U$ infinitely often and $Y_n \in V$ infinitely often.  When this happens the sequence $Y_n$ is certainly not converging.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer!! To show the latter, I came up a different approach, similar to yours: $\{\omega:\lim_{n}X_{n}(\omega)\leq c\}$ is in the tail $\sigma-$algebra for every $c$, and since $X_{n}$ are independent, we can use Kolmogorov $0-1$ law to conclude that if $X_{n}$ converges, then it must converges to a constant a.s. However this cannot be true since $X_{n}$ is non-degenerate, since in this case for every $c$, we must have some $\epsilon$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}(\omega)\leq c-\epsilon)\geq \delta>0$ for every $n$ or

Comment: or  $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}(\omega)\leq c+\epsilon)\geq \delta>0$ for every $n$. In either case, $X_{n}(\omega)$ cannot converges to $c$ almost surely. Thus, it must be that $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega:\lim_{n}X_{n}(\omega)\leq c\})=0$. Am I right?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: Yes, that works too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really nice answer. I never thought about the i.i.d non-degenerate sequence not converging a.s. Thank you!

Comment: You might also find it interesting to prove the following strengthening of that statement: if $Y_n$ are iid, then almost surely, the random set $\{Y_1(\omega), Y_2(\omega), \dots\}$ is dense in the essential range of the $Y_n$ (which is also the support of the distribution measure of the $Y_n$).

Comment: WOW. thank you! I will definitely try to prove this.